# How to import Flask app on test file to make unittest

Tags: python-3.x, rest, api, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to import app from flask to make unittest, but i have trouble with imports:

> Error description: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "tests.py", line 4, in 
>       from app import app   File "/home/master/Workspaces/eduCAT/faq-test/api/app.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from .models import Question, QuestionSchema, Message, MessageSchema ImportError: attempted relative import with no known
>   parent package

I have a file tree with all files in same folder like this:

```
Folder [api]

-> __init__.py

-> app.py

-> models.py

-> test.py

-> config.py
```

The api is running well with **flask run**, but when i try to import **app** to **test.py** i'm getting this error.

Imports:
**app.py**

```
from flask import jsonify, request
from .models import Question, QuestionSchema, Message, MessageSchema
from api import app, db
```

Imports:
**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('api.config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)
```

Imports:
**models.py**

```
from api import db, ma
```

And on the **test.py**

```
import os
import unittest

from app import app
```

Imports that I've already tried on **test.py** :
import:

```
from app import app
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tests.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from app import app   File "/home/master/Workspaces/eduCAT/faq-test/api/app.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from .models import Question, QuestionSchema, Message, MessageSchema ImportError: attempted relative import with no known
>   parent package

import:

```
from .app import app
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tests.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from .app import app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '**main**.app'; '**main**' is not a package

import:

```
from api import app
```

error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "tests.py", line 4, in
>   
>       from api import app ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

Im stucked on this test.

**Edit**
Full code

app.py - https://dpaste.de/JgEi

__init__.py - https://dpaste.de/A9sG

models.py - https://dpaste.de/xEx4

config.py - https://dpaste.de/o8pS

test.py - https://dpaste.de/nGrF

Comment: where is your flask app defined? i.e. this line of code: app = Flask(__name__)

Comment: On \_\_init\_\_.py

`from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_marshmallow import Marshmallow

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('api.config')

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
ma = Marshmallow(app)`

Comment: I believe the issue is you have a file named app.py and you're creating the flask app within your init.py file as a variable also called app so python is having issues deciphering what app you want imported.  Maybe you could rename app.py to something else? Then import app from test.py like so: from api import app

Comment: Renamed app.py to wgsi.py and change the imports to from api import app, still the error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

Comment: @Nathan i've posted the full code, i spent hours trying to make test works, i don't know what to do =/

Comment: @LeandroCampos I know the thread is already 2 years old. But did you find a solution or a work-around back then? Because I am stuck at exactly the same point: I need relative imports to make my Flask app work but Unittest fails to import my self-written modules.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need fix some imports for the code to run...

Example for import objects from **init**.py do you use

```
from . import app, db
```

or create a package named app and input **init**.py inside

Comment: Opa, o app já esta rodando, os imports no __init__. foram para tentar fazer o arquivo de teste funcionar, rodando o app como *flask run* a api funciona normal, o problema esta sendo para importar o *app* do flask dentro do teste.py

O init está assim atualmente mesmo "from . import app, db". Mas quando rodo python test.py. Retorna ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'api'

Comment: Ja tentei dentro do teste.py
"from app import app","from . import app","from .app import app","from api.app import app","from __program__ import app", e nada vai =/