# how to avoid circular reference when importing modules for unittest in flask app?

Tags: python, unit-testing, flask, import, module

I'm trying to run unittest on a flask app but I am having problems when importing the modules necessary to run the test. In summary, the app runs fine and I can check all of its endpoints with curl commands (so far so good). But when I attempt to run the test file, I get a "ModuleNotFoundError:"(pointing at a different module depending on the location from which I run the test and other variables - it gets very nasty and complicated, so bear with me).

Since this is an issue about directories and importing modules and packages between them, let me provide you with the file structure before I continue with the explanation.

> master/ 
> |-- __ init __.py 
> |-- app/ 
> |---- | __ init __.py 
> |---- | app.py 
> |---- | models.py 
> |-- auth/ 
> |---- | __ init __.py 
> |---- | auth.py 
> |-- test/ 
> |---- | __ init __.py 
> |---- | some_test.py

/mastes/app/app.py (simplified)

```
from .models import (
  db,
  setup_db,
  Subject,
  Student,
  subject_student
)

from master.auth.auth import AuthError, requires_auth

def create_app(test_config=None):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.secret_key = os.environ['APP_SECRET_KEY']
    setup_db(app)
    CORS(app)
...
```

At this point, I run the app from the app directory with

> app % FLASK_APP=app.py FLASK_DEBUG=true flask run

No errors. All endpoints work as expected. When I attempt to run the test from the master directory with

> master % python -m unittest test.some_test

output:

> File "......master/app/app.py", line 26 in < module > 
> from master.auth.auth import AuthError, requires_auth 
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'master'

At this point, I go to app.py, and change

> from master.auth.auth import ...

to

> from auth.auth import ....

This fixes the unittest, but then the app.py file breaks when and it is unable to find a module named 'auth' when I run flask.

If I attempt to describe in detail all the solutions I have tried and their outcomes, I think this will become a very unreadable post. So, in summary, some of the solutions I have tried are:

1. adding a relative and absolute path to sys.path in both some_test.py and app.py
2. Run the test from the test folder with

> test % python some_test.py

as opposed to running it from the master directory

3. Moving the entire test directory into the app directory
4. many other trial-and-error attempts.

Since the actual app runs with the above content of the app.py module, I have tried to keep that module consistent.

With every new attempt to run some_test.py, the "ModuleNotFoundError:" persists, either by referencing the app.py file (and some import done there such as 'from master..' or 'from auth ..') or directly in the some_test.py

You can find some of the outcomes I have found in this post: [How to import Flask app on test file to make unittest](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56960633/how-to-import-flask-app-on-test-file-to-make-unittest)

Here is the entire code if anyone wants to see the problem in detail:

https://github.com/Frodriguez9/class-manager

Comment: `PYTHONPATH=/path/to/parent/of/master` should solve it

Comment: @JoranBeasley in fact, it did. Thank you so much!